# How to turn off MediaPlayer on back / home pressed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm looking for a answer, how can I close MediaPlayer when usep will press "back" or "home" button on device.

I have errors when I press back / home or...
Everything is ok when press home but error occure when app is restore.
Can anyone help me with that, I cant find any working code :( ?

Here is my code:

```
package com.gwynbleiddesign.dzwiekizwierzat;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class AnimalDescription extends Activity {

    ImageView animalImage;
    TextView txtNazwa, txtOpisZwierzecia;
    int selectedAnimal = 0;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animal_description);

        Typeface segoeFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/segoeprb.ttf");


        txtNazwa = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAnimalName);
        txtNazwa.setTypeface(segoeFont);
        txtOpisZwierzecia = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAnimalDescription);
        txtOpisZwierzecia.setTypeface(segoeFont);
        animalImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgAnimalPhoto);

        selectedAnimal = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selectedAnimal");

        txtNazwa.setText(dane.nazwy[selectedAnimal]+"");
        animalImage.setImageResource(dane.zdjecia[selectedAnimal]);

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,dane.dzwieki[selectedAnimal]);

        animalImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        mPlayer.start();    
            }
        });
    }
     @Override 
        public void onBackPressed(){  
              mPlayer.reset();
              mPlayer.release();
              mPlayer = null;
              super.onBackPressed();
        }

     @Override 
        public void onPause(){

              //mPlayer.reset();
              mPlayer.release();
              mPlayer = null;
              super.onPause();
        }

     @Override 
        public void onStop(){


              mPlayer.reset();
              mPlayer.release();
              mPlayer = null;
              super.onStop(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post your logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreate` method is called if you run your app for the first time. If you close it and reopen it (and JVM didn't free memory) `onCreate` isn't called again, so your `MediaPlayer` is `null` because `onPause` was triggered when the activity was closed.

Check [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) and initialize your `MediaPlayer` in `onResume`

And please post your `Logcat` next time

Comment: Sorry, I've never copy LogCat :/
need to try :)